# How can I reverse an XOR operation in Assembler?

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, encryption

I am currently trying to write a decryption routine, and one of the steps in the encryption routine is this:

```
xor eax,edx  // xors eax(current character) and edx (the key)
```

Obviously I will know the key so any ideas how I can reverse this operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

XOR is its own inverse. (Bitwise: XOR'ing with 0 will not change a bit. XOR'ing with 1 will flip it, and doing it again will flip it back.)

Just XOR the "encrypted" value and the key again:

```
encrypted = plain XOR key
encrypted XOR key = (plain XOR key) XOR key
encrypted XOR key = plain XOR (key XOR key)
encrypted XOR key = plain XOR (000...0)
encrypted XOR key = plain
```

Comment: So if I XOR eax with 1 I will get the original value?:) sorry Im still learning assembler.

Comment: @JohnPeters: Edited my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

It may help to visualize the behavior of XOR. The XOR operation only sets a Bit, if it is set in just one of the operands. If it is set in both, the result is 0. This is the "eXclusive", otherwise it would just behave like OR:

```
source : 0011
key    : 0101
xor-ed : 0110
```

So, if you just XOR eax (now containing the crypted value) again with the same key in edx, you will get the original source:

```
crypted: 0110
key    : 0101
xor-ed : 0011
```